# Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this method?

Tags: java, android

This method should save the text from an EditText to a file.

This method is in a fragment and I call this method from my MainActivity.java.

```
public void saveState()
    {
        String location="i_C_s_editor_save_state_file.txt";
        String path="file:///data/data/com.wordpress.softwarebycs.i_cseditor/files/"+location;
        File f=new File(path);
        if (f.exists()==true)
            f.delete();
        else{
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = getActivity().openFileOutput(location, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(codebox.getText().toString().getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}

    }
```

Comment: Do you have errors or something ?

Comment: Nope. But when I call it from my MainActivity when I read the file I get the first text saved in it. After that, it doesn't change anymore.

Comment: So I'm guessing that it's something wrong with this save method.

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: `f.delete()` returns a boolean if the file was successfully deleted. Maybe there is some permission error here and the file can't be overwritten.

Comment: Maybe. If I can't overwrite it, what should I do ?

Comment: This could help. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/778288/Saving-data-to-a-file-in-your-Android-application

Comment: If the file exists, why are you deleting it and if it does exist, you skip the write.   If your intention is just to overwrite what is there, that is not needed.

Comment: You should also use getFilesDir() instead of hardcoding the internal path.

Comment: I want to delete any previous instances of that file. Whenever I press a button it should be rewritten.

Comment: The write will overwrite anything that was in the file, unless you choose the MODE_APPEND when opening the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the file exists your code only deletes it:

```
    if (f.exists()==true)
        f.delete();
```

I think you need to add the code to also re-open and save to it i.e.

```
    if (f.exists()==true) {
        f.delete();
       FileOutputStream fos = getActivity().openFileOutput(location, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(codebox.getText().toString().getBytes());
        fos.close();
   }
```

-Dennis

Comment: You're welcome. Any chance you could vote on my answer?

Comment: I don't have 15 reputation. Sorry.